# Slide Effects for Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to make a slide effect between tabs. Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tabs').tabs();
});

$(document).click(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).effect( "slide", "medium" );
});
```

This works but it works if you click anywhere on the page. I want it to work only when you click that tab. I know its because I have to get rid of the "document" from the click function. I've tried replacing "document" with `#tabs`, `#tabs .ui-tabs-nav ul`, `#tabs .ui-tabs-nav li`. What do I put in there for the click function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ..

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tabs').tabs();

   $("#tabs").click(function() {
         $(this).effect( "slide", "medium" );
     });
 });
```

--- Or for tab anchor click :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();

   $("#tabs a").click(function() {
        $('#tabs').effect( "slide", "medium" );
   });
 });
```

Comment: I was testing this out and it seems that the slid effect goes into play if you click the tab region. What if my viewer wants to copy and paste from the tab region? I want to make it so that you only click the actual tab itself, then the tab region slides. 

Right now the tab region slides whenever I click anywhere in the #tab div. I want the #tab div to slide only when I click on the #tab ul. How do I do this?

Comment: U have to give me the html .. in general structure is <div id="tabs" > <ul> <li> <a id="tabs-">.... so u can do somehting like this  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tabs').tabs();
   $('a[id^="tabs-"').click(function() {
         $('#tabs').effect( "slide", "medium" );
     });
 });

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Here is my html. <div id='tabs'>
   <ul>
 <li><a href='#tab1'>Hardware</a></li>
  <li><a href='#tab2'>Software</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#tab3'>Media</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tab1" style='background:silver;'>
                    <p>This is tab 1</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2" style='background:silver;'>
                    <p>This is tab 2</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab3" style='background:silver;'>
                    <p>This is tab 3 </p>
 </div>
 </div>

Comment: yes this will not work as ur id are #tab not #tabs- so i updated the ans.

Comment: when I use the second bit of code, the slide function is gone completely

Comment: sorry my mistake i misunderstood the html .. updated ans now try.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tabs').click(function(){
       $(this).tabs();
     });
 });
```