# Slide Effects for Tabs Part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so my original question got answered and now my slide effect only happens when I click in anywhere in my div region..here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabs').tabs();

$("#tabs").click(function() {
     $(this).effect( "slide", "medium" );
 });
});
```

Now I'm wondering what if somebody wants to copy text from one of my tab regions? Every single time they try to highlight, the tab will slide away. How do I make it so that the tab region only slides when the actualy tab ul is clicked?

Comment: Can you post your earlier question link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215679/slide-effects-for-tabs/22215758?noredirect=1#comment33731935_22215758

Comment: Ok i will add an answer soon.Check it later

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of `mousedown` and `mouseup`:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45NGh/1/)

```
var down=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").mousedown(function(event){
        down=event.clientX+"||"+event.clientY;
    });
    $("#tabs").mouseup(function(event){
        var up=event.clientX+"||"+event.clientY;
        if(up==down)
        $(this).slideUp("medium" );
    });
});
```

---

Updated code which prevent slidedown on **right-click copy text**:

### [Demo Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hKdVx/)

```
var down="||";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").mousedown(function(event){
        switch(event.which){
        case 1:/*Left mouse button pressed*/
            down=event.clientX+"||"+event.clientY;
            break;
        default:/*middle or right mouse button pressed*/
            down="||";
        }
    });
    $("#tabs").mouseup(function(event){
        var up=event.clientX+"||"+event.clientY;
        if(up==down)
        $(this).slideUp("medium" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the event capturing option on click method. By using that, you can get the element on which the mouse is clicked. And then you can use the target object as below,

```
$('#tabs').click(function(e){
     if(e.target.nodeName == 'P') {
         e.stopPropagation();
         return;
     }
     $(this).effect( "slide", "medium" ); 
});
```

Hope it will help.